# Deleted cacerts in Java 7, can I restore it?

Tags: java, security, java-7, keystore

While playing with certificates I have deleted cacerts file from jdk.(usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/security)
Is there anyway to restore it or I have to reinstall jdk?
I am using Ubuntu and Oracle Jdk 7.

Comment: Reinstall the JDK or rollback from backup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as you did not change the file `cacerts` you can restore it simple by reinstalling your JDK or copying it from another installation.